# Extending bootstrap-collapse.js for show and hide methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to extend the [bootstrap-collapse.js plugin](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-collapse.js#L49) and add my own show and hide methods in it.

I want override what are there right now.

Can you help me doing that?

Comment: Help you in what exactly? Overriding them together? Have you tried to override yourself first?

Comment: I am having difficulties overriding that plugin. Can you help me in doing that

Answer (score 0):

You need to redefine these methods in `collapse` prototype.

```
$.fn.collapse.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
   // your code
}
```

But if you want to extend these methods and keep their default behavior you can do so:

```
var tmp = $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.prototype.show;
$.fn.collapse.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
   ...
   tmp.call(this);
   ...
}
```